# No suitable method found for groupingBy for List<String, Integer>

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-8, java-stream

Giving this code :

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("Collect","Collection","by","Collectors");  
Map<String, Long> map = list1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(list1::toString, Collectors.counting()));  
System.out.println(map);
```

It shows me :

> error: no suitable method found for
>   groupingBy(list::toString,Collector< Object,CAP#1,Long>)

I know that if list1 was a  custom class that have let's say getName method and replace list1::toString by list1::getName it would work, but why not toString()?

Comment: Raw types went out of fashion a decade ago.  Add some type parameters.

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)

Comment: What is `list::toString` supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry i just edited my question, it was supposed to be list1::toString not list::toString and List<String> list1 not List list1

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a *class*  and an *object*? `list1` is an object and `list1::toString` is equivalent to `() -> list1.toString()`.

Answer (score 3):

The key of `gorupingBy` should be a method each element of the stream has. Since every element is a `String`, not a `List`, `List::toString` can't be used. Instead, you should apply `toString` to the element. Or since the elements are already strings, just call `Function.indentity`:

```
Map<String, Long> map = 
   list1.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                            (Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: @Mureinik i just edited my question. But toString() is a method in each element in list1 since it's inherited from Object by default, no ?

Comment: @Neokyuubi `list1` isn't an element of the stream. You could use the `Object::toString` or `String::toString` method reference, although calling `toString()` on a `String` isn't very useful.